# Hide table from user

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon layer and a table without geometries. I join the table to the polygons to use one of the table attributes to label the polygons. I don't use the table for anything else.

Is there a way to completely hide the table from the user? I don't want it to show in layer tree:

[image]

Comment: I guess you can't, but you can create a group with these kind of layers. Set your layer required and readonly in your project properties dialog, datasource tab just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the **Invisible layers and groups** plugin:

https://github.com/gacarrillor/InvisibleLayersAndGroups

Comment: it is included in the official plugin repository, so adding it should be quite easy!